# How to create folders using MS OneDrive API from Delphi

Tags: delphi, onedrive

I need to create folders and sub folders on OneDrive using Delphi, so I used indy http component like this

```
var
Params, response: Tstringstream;
Scopes: string;
begin
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
  IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := true;

  Scopes := 'scope=onedrive.readwrite,wl.offline_access,wl.signin';
  //&scope={scope}
  idHTTP1.Get('https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=000000000000008D&'+Scopes
    +'&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf');

  response := Tstringstream.Create;
  Params := Tstringstream.Create('name=FolderA&folder: { }&@name.conflictBehavior:rename');
  idHTTP1.Post('https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root/children', Params, response);
```

I need now to create folders and sub folders how I can do this ?

Here is a syntax from documentation to create a folder but I dont know how to write inside Delphi

```
POST /drive/root/children
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "FolderA",
  "folder": { },
  "@name.conflictBehavior": "rename"
}
```

**Update**:
I tried to get access token like this `response := idHTTP1.Get(...);` but all I got is HTML text, any idea how to get access token ?

Comment: You need to prefix your `Scopes` value with `scope=` in the URL: `Get('https://...?client_id=...&scope='+Scopes+'&...')`

Comment: Once you have authenticated with the server, please read the OneDrive API documentation for how to create folders: https://dev.onedrive.com/misc/appfolder.htm

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I read the documentation here https://dev.onedrive.com/items/create.htm but I dont understand how to use this syntax inside Delphi `POST /drive/root/children`

Comment: You would put the JSON data into a `TStream` object, like `TMemoryStream` or `TStringStream`, and then call Indy's `TIdHTTP.Post()` method to send the JSON data to `https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root/children`. Again, read the documentation: https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm

Comment: I got now `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized.` complete code is in my post above.

Comment: @Remy - It seems to me that the documentation links you should be providing are the ones for OAuth, JSON and the Indy components.  I think once the OP has grasped the basics the OneDrive usage will come naturally, but at this point the question is not about the OneDrive API.

Comment: @Wel: You need to send your authentication token on *every request* once you have obtained it from the server, eg: `IdHTTP1.Post('https://...?access_token='+Token);` or `IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'bearer '+Token;` Also, your `TStringStream` JSON data is malformed, it should be more like this: `Params := TStringStream.Create('{"name": "FolderA", "folder": { }, "@name.conflictBehavior": "rename"}');`

Comment: After `TIdHTTP.Get()` has successfully logged in to the system, you have to retrieve the token from the response, and include the token in subsequent requests.

Comment: To get the response I wrote `response := TIdHTTP.Get(...)` but what I got is very long HTML text.